# In c++ why -> is called binary infix pointer member access operator?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I heard -> is a binary infix pointer member access operator. Now can you explain why does it call so . And what the phrase binary infix mean in this field.

Comment: Why would you want to overload an operator you seem to know nothing about?

Comment: You could say that `->` is a nullary operator. Although, it does have the implicit object argument so if you count that, then it is unary. The arity of a member function depends on your point of view.

Comment: Unary and binary operators, per the standard, can be implemented as non-member functions with one or two parameters respectively. `operator->` must be a non-`static` member and can't be a non-member function. So I'm not sure it qualifies as either.

Comment: You should limit your posts to a [single question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post).

Comment: #Scott Hunter - I post the question to know about.  If I already knew about it,  I would not do so.  I know that -> is a operator that is used with class Or structure type.  I thought that may be a binary operator.  But i read a book where it was overloaded as unary operator,  that's why I post it here.  I google d but unable to find a suitable ans

Comment: Really seems like a binary operator to me, but yeah I wasn't able to find an exact answer on google either.

It's an operator that takes 2 arguments: an object, and an offset (the object member). I don't see any better way of explaining it.

Comment: From a layman's point of view, it feels like a binary operator -- you need something on the LHS and you need something on the RHS. I am not sure how it is from a language lawyer's point of view.

Comment: @S.M.TusharIbneSalam Unfortunately some other user removed the duplicate I've given you. You'll find your answer at [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) and see it doesn't fall in either category of _binary_ or _unary_ operators.

Comment: #MPops- i also thought like you,  that -> is a binary operator as you described.  But I got surprised when I saw that it is overloaded as it is a unary operator .  And that's why I wanted to knew what kind of operator -> is .  If -> would binary operator then I want to eagerly know why it was overloaded as unary operator.  Or it is work as both unary and binary operator like unary - and binary -

Comment: @S.M.TusharIbneSalam BTW use `@<name>` to ping back anyone from comments here, not `#`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Ok, actually this is my first post,  i am getting into it,  and I read your reference site. There -> is told infix binary operator.  I didn't know what infix binary mean. But I googled and read it in "qoura" but I could not understand what is it,  and other things that were told in your given site,  something about recursive call that also was mystery to me

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ should I delete the post,  if you people think that is not a good question

Comment: @S.M.TusharIbneSalam You may want to [edit] your question and elaborate what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: @S.M.TusharIbneSalam "Infix" just means the operator is written between two operands, e.g. `a + b` (as opposed to weird notations like `+ a b` and `a b +`).

Comment: The C++ precedence table refers to first and second argument, making it binary. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation):

> Infix notation ... is characterized by the placement of operators between operands

Again from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation):

> ... a binary operation ... is a calculation that combines two elements (called operands) to produce another element.

In c++ an expression in the [simplified] form `expr -> id-expr` is called a `member access operator expression`. The built-in version provides access to a data member or member function of the class pointed-to by the pointer operand.

Since it takes two expressions to form a `member access operator expression` we might say that it is binary, and since the symbol denoting the operator is placed between the two expressions we might say that it is infix.

Comment: The right-hand "operand" is barely an expression, though.  Grammatically it is an *id-expression*, but instead of being evaluated it is merely looked up (and possibly subjected to overload resolution).  It therefore has to have higher precedence than any binary operation (consider `p->i++`), and the standard terms it a **postfix** expression.